# Static game question

Tags: game-theory

**GAME PROBLEM**

At a  tv game show, two players are handed six cards each. Each of the six cards shows a number, and both players have the same cards. The six numbers are $0,0,3,0,15$. The game is as follows, each one of the players should choose a card, independently of the other player. After this, both players show their selected card. If the numbers agree, both players receive certain amount of money equal to $M > 0$. Define the selection of a number as a strategy. Draw a normal form and find all Nash Equilibria, but one of these seems more plausible than the others. Which one?

---

I tried to write it in the following normal form:

[image: table]

I don't know it this is correct, also, I don't know how to find the Nash Equilibria, can anybody please help me?

Comment: Reading the text again, you should put all "0" cards together as one column/row, because "0" is one strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Trivially, all strategy profiles that lead to payoffs $M$ for both are Nash equilibria. This is a coordination game, where players have no antagonistic interests at all. Both maximize their gains by cooperating, i.e., choosing the same cards.

How do you find Nash equilibria in normal form games? I explained a nice method [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564233/how-to-compute-all-nash-equilibria-in-an-example-of-a-3x3-matrix/564295#564295).

Alternatively, just guess that some strategy profile, say $(0,0)$, is a Nash equilibrium. This is your "equilibrium candidate". Now check if there is some player who strictly prefers to deviate, i.e., chooses another strategy. By definition, if there is no such a deviation, then your candidate is an equilibrium. We only have two players, so checking this can be quickly done. At $(0,0)$, if the column player deviates to "1", he reduces his payoff from $M>0$ to 0, so this is not a profitable deviation. Same for deviations to "3" or "15". Choosing another "0" card gives him $M$ as in the candidate, so there is no deviation that makes him strictly better off (gives him more than $M$). The same holds for the row player and any of the strategy profiles with $M$ for both. Hence, all strategy profiles where both get $M$ are Nash equilibria.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. If players choose their cards independant how do i know what strategy is best (which card i should choose) if i dont know what card my partner is choosing?

Comment: That's the problem with equilibrium analysis: it doesn't tell you how you end up there. Think of it like this: you play the game repeatedly with another player. The first time, you may choose different cards and regret it, because both get 0. Next round, you switch. You switch until both chose the same card and get $M$. At this point, you have "coordinated". There's no reason to switch your card in the next rounds. If you are interested in equilibrium selection, I suggest you read about "focal points". Card 0 would be a focal point here, because it is "reasonable" to coordinate on 0.

Comment: ah i see. thank you for clarifying.